# TSQL XML - Add attribute to parent node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am trying to add an attribute to the out most parent node. attached is my code, my results and my expected results to better understand what I'm trying to do. Any help is much appreciated!

My Code:

```
        SELECT

         (
         SELECT
            (SELECT 
               'quoteRequest' AS '@service'
               FOR XML PATH('request'), TYPE),

        (SELECT
          (SELECT 
            'Add' as Action,
            'generation' AS 'Date/@type',
            'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM' as Date
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT ('Header')),

        (SELECT 
          (SELECT 
            '' AS Status, 
            'CustAcctNum' AS 'Enterprise/@customerAcctNum',
            'Name' AS 'Enterprise/@name',
            'Enterprise Name' AS 'Enterprise'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
         (SELECT 
        'quoteNumber' AS 'ReferenceNumber/@type',
        'true' AS 'ReferenceNumber/@isPrimary',
        'VALUE' AS ReferenceNumber
        FOR XML PATH('ReferenceNumbers'),
        TYPE),

        (SELECT 
        'Special Instructions' AS 'Comment/@type',
        'Comment' AS Comment
        FOR XML PATH('Comments'),
        TYPE),

        (SELECT 
        'Forklift' AS 'EquipmentCode/@desc',
        '1' AS 'EquipmentCode/@qty',
        'DV' AS EquipmentCode
        FOR XML PATH('EquipmentList'),
        TYPE),

        (SELECT(
           SELECT(
             SELECT(
                SELECT
                  'earliest' AS '@type',
                  GETDATE()
                   FOR XML PATH('Date'), TYPE),
               (SELECT
                  'latest' AS '@type',
                  GETDATE()
                   FOR XML PATH('Date'), TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH('Pickup'),TYPE),
          (SELECT(
            SELECT(
              SELECT
                'earliest' AS '@type',
                GETDATE()
                 FOR XML PATH('Date'), TYPE),
             (SELECT
                'latest' AS '@type',
                GETDATE()
                 FOR XML PATH('Date'), TYPE)
               FOR XML PATH('Drop'),TYPE))
             FOR XML PATH('Dates'), TYPE)),

        (SELECT
          (SELECT
            (SELECT 
            'false' AS '@isresidential',
            '' AS 'Alias',
            'Name' AS 'Name',
            'AddrLine1' AS 'AddrLine1',
            'AddrLine2' AS 'AddrLine2',
            'City' AS 'City',
            'StateProvince' AS 'StateProvince',
            'PostalCode' AS 'PostalCode',
            'CountryCode' AS 'CountryCode',
            (SELECT
               'Name' AS 'Name',
                 (SELECT 
                    'phone' AS 'ContactMethod/@type',
                    '1' AS 'ContactMethod/@sequenceNum',
                    '8675309' AS 'ContactMethod'
                     FOR XML PATH('ContactMethods'), TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH('Contact'), TYPE, ROOT('Contacts')),
            (SELECT 
               'Comments' as 'Comments'
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE)

            FOR XML PATH('Address'), TYPE)

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Shipper'))),

        (SELECT
           (SELECT

            (SELECT 
            'false' AS '@isresidential',
            '' AS 'Alias',
            'Name' AS 'Name',
            'AddrLine1' AS 'AddrLine1',
            'AddrLine2' AS 'AddrLine2',
            'City' AS 'City',
            'StateProvince' AS 'StateProvince',
            'PostalCode' AS 'PostalCode',
            'CountryCode' AS 'CountryCode',
            (SELECT
               'Name' AS 'Name',
                 (SELECT 
                    'phone' AS 'ContactMethod/@type',
                    '1' AS 'ContactMethod/@sequenceNum',
                    '8675309' AS 'ContactMethod'
                     FOR XML PATH('ContactMethods'), TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH('Contact'), TYPE, ROOT('Contacts')),
            (SELECT 
               'Comments' as 'Comments'
                FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE)

            FOR XML PATH('Address'), TYPE)

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Consignee'))),
        (
        SELECT(

        SELECT(
            (SELECT 
            'false' AS '@stackable',
            '1' AS '@sequence',
            (SELECT 
               'UOM' AS 'Quantity/@units',
               '1' AS 'Quantity'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
            (SELECT 
               'UOM' AS 'Weight/@units',
               '1' AS 'Weight'
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
                (SELECT 
                '1' AS '@height',   
                '1' AS '@units',   
                '1' AS '@width',
                '1' AS '@length'  
                FOR XML PATH('Dimensions'), TYPE),
                (SELECT
                'freghtClass' AS '@freightClass',
                '1' AS '@sequence',
                (SELECT 
                   'UOM' AS 'Weight/@units',
                   '1' AS 'Weight'
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
                    (SELECT 
                    '1' AS '@height',   
                    '1' AS '@units',   
                    '1' AS '@width',
                    '1' AS '@length'  
                    FOR XML PATH('Dimensions'), TYPE),
                '1' AS 'Quantity'
                FOR XML PATH('Item'), TYPE, ROOT('Items'))

            FOR XML PATH('HandlingUnit'), TYPE))

          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('HandlingUnits'))),

        (
        SELECT(
          SELECT 'Method' AS Method
             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),
            (SELECT 'true' AS '@thirdParty',

            (SELECT 
            'false' AS '@isresidential',
            '' AS 'Alias',
            'Name' AS 'Name',
            'AddrLine1' AS 'AddrLine1',
            'AddrLine2' AS 'AddrLine2',
            'City' AS 'City',
            'StateProvince' AS 'StateProvince',
            'PostalCode' AS 'PostalCode',
            'CountryCode' AS 'CountryCode',
            (SELECT
               'Name' AS 'Name',
                 (SELECT 
                    'phone' AS 'ContactMethod/@type',
                    '1' AS 'ContactMethod/@sequenceNum',
                    '8675309' AS 'ContactMethod'
                     FOR XML PATH('ContactMethods'), TYPE)
                FOR XML PATH('Contact'), TYPE, ROOT('Contacts'))

            FOR XML PATH('Address'), TYPE)
           FOR XML PATH('BillTo'), TYPE)

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Payment'))

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('Shipment'))

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('QuoteRequest'))

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('request'))
```

My results. Note the first two lines:

```
      **<request>
        <request service="quoteRequest" />**
        <QuoteRequest>
          <Header>
            <Action>Add</Action>
            <Date type="generation">MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM</Date>
          </Header>
          <Shipment>
            <Status />
            <Enterprise customerAcctNum="CustAcctNum" name="Name">Enterprise Name</Enterprise>
            <ReferenceNumbers>
              <ReferenceNumber type="quoteNumber" isPrimary="true">VALUE</ReferenceNumber>
            </ReferenceNumbers>
            <Comments>
              <Comment type="Special Instructions">Comment</Comment>
            </Comments>
            <EquipmentList>
              <EquipmentCode desc="Forklift" qty="1">DV</EquipmentCode>
            </EquipmentList>
            <Dates>
              <Pickup>
                <Date type="earliest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
                <Date type="latest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
              </Pickup>
              <Drop>
                <Date type="earliest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
                <Date type="latest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
              </Drop>
            </Dates>
            <Shipper>
              <Address isresidential="false">
                <Alias />
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <AddrLine1>AddrLine1</AddrLine1>
                <AddrLine2>AddrLine2</AddrLine2>
                <City>City</City>
                <StateProvince>StateProvince</StateProvince>
                <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
                <Contacts>
                  <Contact>
                    <Name>Name</Name>
                    <ContactMethods>
                      <ContactMethod type="phone" sequenceNum="1">8675309</ContactMethod>
                    </ContactMethods>
                  </Contact>
                </Contacts>
                <Comments>Comments</Comments>
              </Address>
            </Shipper>
            <Consignee>
              <Address isresidential="false">
                <Alias />
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <AddrLine1>AddrLine1</AddrLine1>
                <AddrLine2>AddrLine2</AddrLine2>
                <City>City</City>
                <StateProvince>StateProvince</StateProvince>
                <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
                <Contacts>
                  <Contact>
                    <Name>Name</Name>
                    <ContactMethods>
                      <ContactMethod type="phone" sequenceNum="1">8675309</ContactMethod>
                    </ContactMethods>
                  </Contact>
                </Contacts>
                <Comments>Comments</Comments>
              </Address>
            </Consignee>
            <HandlingUnits>
              <HandlingUnit stackable="false" sequence="1">
                <Quantity units="UOM">1</Quantity>
                <Weight units="UOM">1</Weight>
                <Dimensions height="1" units="1" width="1" length="1" />
                <Items>
                  <Item freightClass="freghtClass" sequence="1">
                    <Weight units="UOM">1</Weight>
                    <Dimensions height="1" units="1" width="1" length="1" />
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </HandlingUnit>
            </HandlingUnits>
            <Payment>
              <Method>Method</Method>
              <BillTo thirdParty="true">
                <Address isresidential="false">
                  <Alias />
                  <Name>Name</Name>
                  <AddrLine1>AddrLine1</AddrLine1>
                  <AddrLine2>AddrLine2</AddrLine2>
                  <City>City</City>
                  <StateProvince>StateProvince</StateProvince>
                  <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
                  <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
                  <Contacts>
                    <Contact>
                      <Name>Name</Name>
                      <ContactMethods>
                        <ContactMethod type="phone" sequenceNum="1">8675309</ContactMethod>
                      </ContactMethods>
                    </Contact>
                  </Contacts>
                </Address>
              </BillTo>
            </Payment>
          </Shipment>
        </QuoteRequest>
      </request>
```

My expected results, note the very first line/node is request. Unlike the results I get above, i need the node and attribute to be on the same line:

```
      **<request service=quoteRequest">**
        <QuoteRequest>
          <Header>
            <Action>Add</Action>
            <Date type="generation">MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM</Date>
          </Header>
          <Shipment>
            <Status />
            <Enterprise customerAcctNum="CustAcctNum" name="Name">Enterprise Name</Enterprise>
            <ReferenceNumbers>
              <ReferenceNumber type="quoteNumber" isPrimary="true">VALUE</ReferenceNumber>
            </ReferenceNumbers>
            <Comments>
              <Comment type="Special Instructions">Comment</Comment>
            </Comments>
            <EquipmentList>
              <EquipmentCode desc="Forklift" qty="1">DV</EquipmentCode>
            </EquipmentList>
            <Dates>
              <Pickup>
                <Date type="earliest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
                <Date type="latest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
              </Pickup>
              <Drop>
                <Date type="earliest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
                <Date type="latest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
              </Drop>
            </Dates>
            <Shipper>
              <Address isresidential="false">
                <Alias />
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <AddrLine1>AddrLine1</AddrLine1>
                <AddrLine2>AddrLine2</AddrLine2>
                <City>City</City>
                <StateProvince>StateProvince</StateProvince>
                <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
                <Contacts>
                  <Contact>
                    <Name>Name</Name>
                    <ContactMethods>
                      <ContactMethod type="phone" sequenceNum="1">8675309</ContactMethod>
                    </ContactMethods>
                  </Contact>
                </Contacts>
                <Comments>Comments</Comments>
              </Address>
            </Shipper>
            <Consignee>
              <Address isresidential="false">
                <Alias />
                <Name>Name</Name>
                <AddrLine1>AddrLine1</AddrLine1>
                <AddrLine2>AddrLine2</AddrLine2>
                <City>City</City>
                <StateProvince>StateProvince</StateProvince>
                <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
                <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
                <Contacts>
                  <Contact>
                    <Name>Name</Name>
                    <ContactMethods>
                      <ContactMethod type="phone" sequenceNum="1">8675309</ContactMethod>
                    </ContactMethods>
                  </Contact>
                </Contacts>
                <Comments>Comments</Comments>
              </Address>
            </Consignee>
            <HandlingUnits>
              <HandlingUnit stackable="false" sequence="1">
                <Quantity units="UOM">1</Quantity>
                <Weight units="UOM">1</Weight>
                <Dimensions height="1" units="1" width="1" length="1" />
                <Items>
                  <Item freightClass="freghtClass" sequence="1">
                    <Weight units="UOM">1</Weight>
                    <Dimensions height="1" units="1" width="1" length="1" />
                    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                  </Item>
                </Items>
              </HandlingUnit>
            </HandlingUnits>
            <Payment>
              <Method>Method</Method>
              <BillTo thirdParty="true">
                <Address isresidential="false">
                  <Alias />
                  <Name>Name</Name>
                  <AddrLine1>AddrLine1</AddrLine1>
                  <AddrLine2>AddrLine2</AddrLine2>
                  <City>City</City>
                  <StateProvince>StateProvince</StateProvince>
                  <PostalCode>PostalCode</PostalCode>
                  <CountryCode>CountryCode</CountryCode>
                  <Contacts>
                    <Contact>
                      <Name>Name</Name>
                      <ContactMethods>
                        <ContactMethod type="phone" sequenceNum="1">8675309</ContactMethod>
                      </ContactMethods>
                    </Contact>
                  </Contacts>
                </Address>
              </BillTo>
            </Payment>
          </Shipment>
        </QuoteRequest>
      </request>
```

I've tried many different things and still cant get it to work correctly. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I want to take a step back and question why you are making the data as complex as it is with selects over and over and over?  I would break it up into sections potentially of Shipment, Shipper, etc if it very complex and making a giant tablix but you should be able to make the elements independent of any tree structure and then readd them as needed.  In a mock up I can show what I mean.  Using the more explicit 'XML Path()' you have more options for creation of artifical nodes and don't have to nest selects just for creating node names.  EG:

```
DECLARE @People TABLE (PersonId INT IDENTITY, PersonName VARCHAR(128));

INSERT INTO @People (PersonName) VALUES ('Brett'), ('John'), ('Mark'), ('Shawn'), ('Ryan'), ('Kevin');

DECLARE @XmlResults XML = 

(
SELECT 
  CAST(
    Replace(
    (SELECT 
      'quoteRequest' AS "@service"
    , 'Add' AS "QuoteRequest/Header/Action/*"
    , 'generation' AS "QuoteRequest/Header/Date/@type"
    , 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM' AS "QuoteRequest/Header/Date/*"
    , '' AS "QuoteRequest/Shipment/Status/*"
    , 'CustAcctNum' AS "QuoteRequest/Shipment/Enterprise/@customerAcctNum"
    , 'Name' AS "QuoteRequest/Shipment/Enterprise/@name"
    , PersonName AS "QuoteRequest/Shipment/Enterprise/*"
    , 'earliest' AS "QuoteRequest/Dates/Pickup/Date/@type"
    , FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff', 'en-US') AS "QuoteRequest/Dates/Pickup/Date/*"
    , 'latest' AS "QuoteRequest/Dates/Pickup/DateTwo/@type"
    , FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff', 'en-US') AS "QuoteRequest/Dates/Pickup/DateTwo/*"
    From @People
    FOR XML PATH('request'), ROOT('Requests'))
    , 'DateTwo', 'Date')
  AS XML)
)

--XML as is
SELECT @XmlResults

--XML parsed for one request at a time in my series.
SELECT x.query('.')
FROM @XmlResults.nodes('Requests/request') AS y(x)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason why I did it like this is because this is the first time I have created XML with SQL. So I am not well versed in the best practices and I don't have the luxury of time to do much research unfortunately. What you have done in your mock-up looks like it would work great and keep performance healthy. How would you create nodes using your method that aren't closed off after the attribute is defined? Like the "BillTo" and "Address" Nodes in the "Payment" node above?

Comment: Well it really depends on how complex the data is to get.  If you could get a sql server result returned in a fairly fast time for your complex data fast, than just get it all in one go with all the joins.  Else break it up with CTE's, table variables, nested selects, etc.  You can make different tree structures of nodes.  In my example 'Person' and 'Orders' are both their own structures of nodes.  If you are never getting data from the SQL Server and just arbitrarily making xml it is even easier.

Comment: The data wont be too difficult to retrieve. Maybe 2 or 3 tables to join on. I had planned on getting all the necessary data before the XML generation, setting them to parameters then reference those parameters in the XML generation.

Comment: Are you doing a result set based operation or just a single one at a time for this?  You could make your example regardless of how complex you make it go over a series rather than just one thing at a time.  I updated my example for your code more but presupposing data I could iterate over.  I did not do everything as your xml structure is LARGE.

Comment: What you recommended is working great. One issue I have is how to generate the "Dates" block in the expected results i posted originally. As you can see, "Date" is used twice as a element in the Pickup node and SQL does not like that. Unfortunately, the XML needs to be sent that way. Do you have any ideas how to get around that with your method?

      <Dates>
       <Pickup>
        <Date type=""></Date>
       </Pickup>
       <Drop>
        <Date type=""></Date>
       </Drop>
      </Dates>

Comment: Not that hard, I updated my example.  You just need a format set up for it.

Comment: That works great if you need 1 Date. I need that DATE element twice in a row within the Pickup Node. Like in the "Dates" Node in my expected results above.

              <Pickup>

                <Date type="earliest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
                <Date type="latest">2017-06-12T08:20:27.107</Date>
              </Pickup>

Comment: Technically doing the repeat <thing><Date /><Date /></thing> is a bad idea as you are repeating structure that should be distinct.  But I can get around that by simply sticking to my method and naming it something different.  Nesting that and then replacing it with the name already used.  Then casting that back into XML.  It's valid xml but just not best practice.   Anyways I updated my example to get what you need.

Comment: I agree that its a bad idea, unfortunately that is what the company requires... Thanks for all your help!