# TSQL XML Add a child note within an artificial node in explicit XML Path

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, subquery

I'm trying to create an XML in SQL Server that contains one order. One order may have multiple shipments based on certain criteria. There are several nodes so i was able to get the XML built using artificial nodes with the help of djangojazz ([TSQL XML - Add attribute to parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44503209/tsql-xml-add-attribute-to-parent-node/44504079?noredirect=1#comment76012948_44504079)). Everything is coming together well except for one piece. Within the XML there is an "Items" Node. There could be several items within a shipment, but with the way I am using the artificial nodes, i can't quite successfully get the layers of individual items within the Items node correctly. The code is creating a duplicate Shipment ID Node with each unique Item. I have surrounded the code/XML in question with *'s below.

My Select statement:

```
    SELECT 

        --Shipment
        --Enterprise
        'Pending' AS 'Status',
        orm.cust_po_number AS 'Enterprise/@customerAcctNum',
        orm.customer_name AS 'Enterprise/@name',
        '' AS 'Enterprise/*',
        --Ref Numbers
        'ShipmentID' AS 'ReferenceNumbers/ReferenceNumber/@type',
        'true' AS 'ReferenceNumbers/ReferenceNumber/@isPrimary',
        ord.order_number + '.' + CAST(RIGHT('0000000000'+CAST(ord.shipment_sequence AS VARCHAR(3)),10) AS VARCHAR) AS 'ReferenceNumbers/ReferenceNumber/*',
        'QuoteNumber' AS 'ReferenceNumbers/ReferenceNumberTwo/@type',
        'false' AS 'ReferenceNumbers/ReferenceNumberTwo/@isPrimary',
        orm.quote_number AS 'ReferenceNumbers/ReferenceNumberTwo/*',
        --Ship Comments
        --'SpecialInstructions' AS 'Comments/Comment/@type',
        '' AS 'Comments/Comment/*',
        --Equipment List    
        '' AS 'EquipmentList/EquipmentCode/@desc',
        '' AS 'EquipmentList/EquipmentCode/@qty',
        '' AS 'EquipmentList/EquipmentCode/*',
        --Dates
        'earliest' AS 'Dates/Pickup/Date/@type',
        FORMAT(ord.schedule_ship, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'en-US') AS 'Dates/Pickup/Date/*',
        'latest' AS 'Dates/Pickup/DateTwo/@type',
        FORMAT(ord.schedule_ship, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'en-US') AS 'Dates/Pickup/DateTwo/*',
        'earliest' AS 'Dates/Drop/Date/@type',
        FORMAT(ord.schedule_ship, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'en-US') AS 'Dates/Drop/Date/*',
        'latest' AS 'Dates/Drop/DateTwo/@type',
        FORMAT(ord.schedule_ship, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm', 'en-US') AS 'Dates/Drop/DateTwo/*',
        --Shipper
        'false' AS 'Shipper/Address/@isResidential',
        '' AS 'Shipper/Address/Alias',
        ord.ship_from_name AS 'Shipper/Address/Name',
        ord.ship_from_addr1 AS 'Shipper/Address/AddrLine1',
        ord.ship_from_addr2 AS 'Shipper/Address/AddrLine2',
        ord.ship_from_city AS 'Shipper/Address/City',
        ord.ship_from_state AS 'Shipper/Address/StateProvince',
        ord.ship_from_zip AS 'Shipper/Address/PostalCode',
        ord.ship_from_country_code AS 'Shipper/Address/CountryCode',
        '' AS 'Shipper/Address/Contacts/Contact/Name/*',
        '' AS 'Shipper/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/@type',
        '' AS 'Shipper/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/@sequenceNum',
        '' AS 'Shipper/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/*',
        '' AS 'Shipper/Address/Comments',
        --Consignee
        CASE 
            WHEN ord.ship_to_is_residential = 'Y'
            THEN 'true'
            ELSE 'false'
        END AS 'Consignee/Address/@isResidential',
        '' AS 'Consignee/Address/Alias',
        orm.ship_to_name AS 'Consignee/Address/Name',
        orm.ship_to_addr1 AS 'Consignee/Address/AddrLine1',
        orm.ship_to_addr2 AS 'Consignee/Address/AddrLine2',
        orm.ship_to_city AS 'Consignee/Address/City',
        orm.ship_to_state AS 'Consignee/Address/StateProvince',
        orm.ship_to_zip AS 'Consignee/Address/PostalCode',
        orm.ship_to_country_code AS 'Consignee/Address/CountryCode',
        '' AS 'Consignee/Address/Contacts/Contact/Name/*',
        '' AS 'Consignee/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/@type',
        '' AS 'Consignee/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/@sequenceNum',
        '' AS 'Consignee/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/*',
        '' AS 'Consignee/Address/Comments',
        --Handling Units
        'false' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/@stackable',
        'Pallet' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Quantity/@units',
        CAST(SUM(ord.qty) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Quantity/*',
        'lb' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Weight/@units',
        CAST(SUM(ord.extended_weight) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Weight/*',
        CAST(SUM(ord.container_height) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Dimensions/@height',
        'in' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Dimensions/@units',
        CAST(SUM(ord.container_width) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Dimensions/@width',
        CAST(SUM(ord.container_length) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Dimensions/@length',

        --********************************
        '' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/*',
        ord.freight_class AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/@FreightClass',
        '1' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/@sequence',
        'lb' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Weight/@units',
        CAST(SUM(ord.extended_weight) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Weight/*',
        CAST(SUM(ord.container_height) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Dimensions/@height',
        'in' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Dimensions/@units',
        CAST(SUM(ord.container_width) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Dimensions/@width',
        CAST(SUM(ord.container_length) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Dimensions/@length',
        '' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Quantity/@units',
        CAST(SUM(ord.qty) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/Quantity/*',
        '' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/NMFC/*',
        'false' AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/Items/Item/HazardousMaterial/*',
        --******************************** 

        --Payment   
        CASE 
            WHEN ord.ship_from_addr1 = @v_vchWengerAdd
                    AND ord.ship_from_zip = @v_vchWengerZip
            THEN 'Prepaid'
            ELSE 'Third Party'
        END AS 'Payment/Method',
        CASE 
            WHEN ord.ship_from_addr1 = @v_vchWengerAdd
                    AND ord.ship_from_zip = @v_vchWengerZip
            THEN 'false'
            ELSE 'true'
        END AS 'Payment/BillTo/@thirdParty',
        CASE 
            WHEN ord.ship_to_is_residential = 'Y'
            THEN 'true'
            ELSE 'false'
        END AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/@isresidential',
        '' AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/Alias',
        orm.bill_to_name AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/Name',
        orm.bill_to_addr1 AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/AddrLine1',
        orm.bill_to_addr2 AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/AddrLine2',
        orm.bill_to_city AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/City',
        orm.bill_to_state AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/StateProvince',
        orm.bill_to_zip AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/PostalCode',
        orm.bill_to_addr1 AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/CountryCode',
        '' AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/Contacts/Contact/Name/*',
        '' AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/@type',
        '' AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/@sequenceNum',
        '' AS 'Payment/BillTo/Address/Contacts/Contact/ContactMethods/ContactMethod/*'

        FROM t_order_detail ord WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN t_order orm WITH (NOLOCK) 
        ON ord.wh_id = orm.wh_id
        AND ord.order_number = orm.order_number
    WHERE ord.wh_id = @in_vchWhID
        AND ord.order_number = @in_vchOrderNumber

    GROUP BY ord.shipment_sequence, ord.order_number, orm.quote_number, orm.cust_po_number, orm.customer_name, ord.schedule_ship,   ord.ship_from_name,
                ord.ship_from_addr1, ord.ship_from_addr2, ord.ship_from_city, ord.ship_from_state,  ord.ship_from_zip, ord.ship_from_country_code,
                ord.ship_to_is_residential, orm.ship_to_name, orm.ship_to_addr1, orm.ship_to_addr2, orm.ship_to_city, orm.ship_to_state,
                orm.ship_to_zip, orm.ship_to_country_code, ord.freight_class, orm.bill_to_name, orm.bill_to_addr1, orm.bill_to_addr2,
                orm.bill_to_city,orm.bill_to_state, orm.bill_to_zip

    FOR XML PATH('Shipment'), TYPE
```

Result:

```
    <Shipment>
      <Status>Pending</Status>
      <Enterprise customerAcctNum="SIGNED QUOTE" name="CHRIS STORJOHANN"></Enterprise>
      <ReferenceNumbers>
        <ReferenceNumber type="ShipmentID" isPrimary="true">1564301.0000000043</ReferenceNumber>
        <ReferenceNumberTwo type="QuoteNumber" isPrimary="false" />
      </ReferenceNumbers>
      <Comments>
        <Comment></Comment>
      </Comments>
      <EquipmentList>
        <EquipmentCode desc="" qty=""></EquipmentCode>
      </EquipmentList>
      <Dates>
        <Pickup>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Pickup>
        <Drop>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Drop>
      </Dates>
      <Shipper>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Name>WENGER CORPORATION</Name>
          <AddrLine1>555 PARK DR</AddrLine1>
          <City>OWATONNA</City>
          <StateProvince>MN</StateProvince>
          <PostalCode>55060-4980</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Shipper>
      <Consignee>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Consignee>
      <HandlingUnits>
        <HandlingUnit stackable="false">
          <Quantity units="Pallet">83.0</Quantity>
          <Weight units="lb">153.9</Weight>
          <Dimensions height="75.6" units="in" width="31.1" length="72.6" />
          ***************************************************
            <Items>
            <Item FreightClass="065" sequence="1">
              <Weight units="lb">153.9</Weight>
              <Dimensions height="75.6" units="in" width="31.1" length="72.6" />
              <Quantity units="">83.0</Quantity>
              <NMFC></NMFC>
              <HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial>
            </Item>
          </Items>
        *****************************************************
        </HandlingUnit>
      </HandlingUnits>
      <Payment>
        <Method>Prepaid</Method>
        <BillTo thirdParty="false">
          <Address isresidential="false">
            <Alias></Alias>
            <Name>Valdosta Lowndes Conf. Ctr.</Name>
            <AddrLine1>1 Meeting Pl</AddrLine1>
            <City>Valdosta</City>
            <StateProvince>GA</StateProvince>
            <PostalCode>316017710</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>1 Meeting Pl</CountryCode>
            <Contacts>
              <Contact>
                <Name></Name>
                <ContactMethods>
                  <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
                </ContactMethods>
              </Contact>
            </Contacts>
          </Address>
        </BillTo>
      </Payment>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
      <Status>Pending</Status>
      <Enterprise customerAcctNum="SIGNED QUOTE" name="CHRIS STORJOHANN"></Enterprise>
      <ReferenceNumbers>
        <ReferenceNumber type="ShipmentID" isPrimary="true">1564301.0000000043</ReferenceNumber>
        <ReferenceNumberTwo type="QuoteNumber" isPrimary="false" />
      </ReferenceNumbers>
      <Comments>
        <Comment></Comment>
      </Comments>
      <EquipmentList>
        <EquipmentCode desc="" qty=""></EquipmentCode>
      </EquipmentList>
      <Dates>
        <Pickup>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Pickup>
        <Drop>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Drop>
      </Dates>
      <Shipper>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Name>WENGER CORPORATION</Name>
          <AddrLine1>555 PARK DR</AddrLine1>
          <City>OWATONNA</City>
          <StateProvince>MN</StateProvince>
          <PostalCode>55060-4980</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Shipper>
      <Consignee>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Consignee>
      <HandlingUnits>
        <HandlingUnit stackable="false">
          <Quantity units="Pallet">1.0</Quantity>
          <Weight units="lb">85.0</Weight>
          <Dimensions height="12.1" units="in" width="5.7" length="10.6" />
            **************************************************************
          <Items>
            <Item FreightClass="085" sequence="1">
              <Weight units="lb">85.0</Weight>
              <Dimensions height="12.1" units="in" width="5.7" length="10.6" />
              <Quantity units="">1.0</Quantity>
              <NMFC></NMFC>
              <HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial>
            </Item>
          </Items>
            **************************************************************
        </HandlingUnit>
      </HandlingUnits>
      <Payment>
        <Method>Prepaid</Method>
        <BillTo thirdParty="false">
          <Address isresidential="false">
            <Alias></Alias>
            <Name>Valdosta Lowndes Conf. Ctr.</Name>
            <AddrLine1>1 Meeting Pl</AddrLine1>
            <City>Valdosta</City>
            <StateProvince>GA</StateProvince>
            <PostalCode>316017710</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>1 Meeting Pl</CountryCode>
            <Contacts>
              <Contact>
                <Name></Name>
                <ContactMethods>
                  <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
                </ContactMethods>
              </Contact>
            </Contacts>
          </Address>
        </BillTo>
      </Payment>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
      <Status>Pending</Status>
      <Enterprise customerAcctNum="SIGNED QUOTE" name="CHRIS STORJOHANN"></Enterprise>
      <ReferenceNumbers>
        <ReferenceNumber type="ShipmentID" isPrimary="true">1564301.0000000044</ReferenceNumber>
        <ReferenceNumberTwo type="QuoteNumber" isPrimary="false" />
      </ReferenceNumbers>
      <Comments>
        <Comment></Comment>
      </Comments>
      <EquipmentList>
        <EquipmentCode desc="" qty=""></EquipmentCode>
      </EquipmentList>
      <Dates>
        <Pickup>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Pickup>
        <Drop>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Drop>
      </Dates>
      <Shipper>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Name>CHARTER BUILDERS, INC.</Name>
          <AddrLine1>STE 700</AddrLine1>
          <AddrLine2>1505 LYNDON B JOHNSON FWY</AddrLine2>
          <City>DALLAS</City>
          <StateProvince>TX</StateProvince>
          <PostalCode>75234-6065</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Shipper>
      <Consignee>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Consignee>
      <HandlingUnits>
        <HandlingUnit stackable="false">
          <Quantity units="Pallet">54.0</Quantity>
          <Weight units="lb">49.6</Weight>
          <Dimensions height="21.3" units="in" width="10.9" length="36.1" />
          <Items>
            <Item FreightClass="065" sequence="1">
              <Weight units="lb">49.6</Weight>
              <Dimensions height="21.3" units="in" width="10.9" length="36.1" />
              <Quantity units="">54.0</Quantity>
              <NMFC></NMFC>
              <HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial>
            </Item>
          </Items>
        </HandlingUnit>
      </HandlingUnits>
      <Payment>
        <Method>Third Party</Method>
        <BillTo thirdParty="true">
          <Address isresidential="false">
            <Alias></Alias>
            <Name>Valdosta Lowndes Conf. Ctr.</Name>
            <AddrLine1>1 Meeting Pl</AddrLine1>
            <City>Valdosta</City>
            <StateProvince>GA</StateProvince>
            <PostalCode>316017710</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>1 Meeting Pl</CountryCode>
            <Contacts>
              <Contact>
                <Name></Name>
                <ContactMethods>
                  <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
                </ContactMethods>
              </Contact>
            </Contacts>
          </Address>
        </BillTo>
      </Payment>
    </Shipment>
```

Desired Result:

```
    <Shipment>
      <Status>Pending</Status>
      <Enterprise customerAcctNum="SIGNED QUOTE" name="CHRIS STORJOHANN"></Enterprise>
      <ReferenceNumbers>
        <ReferenceNumber type="ShipmentID" isPrimary="true">1564301.0000000043</ReferenceNumber>
        <ReferenceNumberTwo type="QuoteNumber" isPrimary="false" />
      </ReferenceNumbers>
      <Comments>
        <Comment></Comment>
      </Comments>
      <EquipmentList>
        <EquipmentCode desc="" qty=""></EquipmentCode>
      </EquipmentList>
      <Dates>
        <Pickup>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Pickup>
        <Drop>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Drop>
      </Dates>
      <Shipper>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Name>WENGER CORPORATION</Name>
          <AddrLine1>555 PARK DR</AddrLine1>
          <City>OWATONNA</City>
          <StateProvince>MN</StateProvince>
          <PostalCode>55060-4980</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Shipper>
      <Consignee>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Consignee>
      <HandlingUnits>
        <HandlingUnit stackable="false">
          <Quantity units="Pallet">83.0</Quantity>
          <Weight units="lb">153.9</Weight>
          <Dimensions height="75.6" units="in" width="31.1" length="72.6" />
          ****************************************************
            <Items>
            <Item FreightClass="065" sequence="1">
              <Weight units="lb">153.9</Weight>
              <Dimensions height="75.6" units="in" width="31.1" length="72.6" />
              <Quantity units="">83.0</Quantity>
              <NMFC></NMFC>
              <HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial>
            </Item>
            <Item FreightClass="085" sequence="1">
             <Weight units="lb">85.0</Weight>
             <Dimensions height="12.1" units="in" width="5.7" length="10.6" />
             <Quantity units="">1.0</Quantity>
             <NMFC></NMFC>
             <HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial>
            </Item>   
          </Items>
        ******************************************************
        </HandlingUnit>
      </HandlingUnits>
      <Payment>
        <Method>Prepaid</Method>
        <BillTo thirdParty="false">
          <Address isresidential="false">
            <Alias></Alias>
            <Name>Valdosta Lowndes Conf. Ctr.</Name>
            <AddrLine1>1 Meeting Pl</AddrLine1>
            <City>Valdosta</City>
            <StateProvince>GA</StateProvince>
            <PostalCode>316017710</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>1 Meeting Pl</CountryCode>
            <Contacts>
              <Contact>
                <Name></Name>
                <ContactMethods>
                  <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
                </ContactMethods>
              </Contact>
            </Contacts>
          </Address>
        </BillTo>
      </Payment>
    </Shipment>
    <Shipment>
      <Status>Pending</Status>
      <Enterprise customerAcctNum="SIGNED QUOTE" name="CHRIS STORJOHANN"></Enterprise>
      <ReferenceNumbers>
        <ReferenceNumber type="ShipmentID" isPrimary="true">1564301.0000000044</ReferenceNumber>
        <ReferenceNumberTwo type="QuoteNumber" isPrimary="false" />
      </ReferenceNumbers>
      <Comments>
        <Comment></Comment>
      </Comments>
      <EquipmentList>
        <EquipmentCode desc="" qty=""></EquipmentCode>
      </EquipmentList>
      <Dates>
        <Pickup>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Pickup>
        <Drop>
          <Date type="earliest">2014/02/26 00:00</Date>
          <DateTwo type="latest">2014/02/26 00:00</DateTwo>
        </Drop>
      </Dates>
      <Shipper>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Name>CHARTER BUILDERS, INC.</Name>
          <AddrLine1>STE 700</AddrLine1>
          <AddrLine2>1505 LYNDON B JOHNSON FWY</AddrLine2>
          <City>DALLAS</City>
          <StateProvince>TX</StateProvince>
          <PostalCode>75234-6065</PostalCode>
          <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Shipper>
      <Consignee>
        <Address isResidential="false">
          <Alias></Alias>
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name></Name>
              <ContactMethods>
                <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
              </ContactMethods>
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Comments></Comments>
        </Address>
      </Consignee>
      <HandlingUnits>
        <HandlingUnit stackable="false">
          <Quantity units="Pallet">54.0</Quantity>
          <Weight units="lb">49.6</Weight>
          <Dimensions height="21.3" units="in" width="10.9" length="36.1" />
          <Items>
            <Item FreightClass="065" sequence="1">
              <Weight units="lb">49.6</Weight>
              <Dimensions height="21.3" units="in" width="10.9" length="36.1" />
              <Quantity units="">54.0</Quantity>
              <NMFC></NMFC>
              <HazardousMaterial>false</HazardousMaterial>
            </Item>
          </Items>
        </HandlingUnit>
      </HandlingUnits>
      <Payment>
        <Method>Third Party</Method>
        <BillTo thirdParty="true">
          <Address isresidential="false">
            <Alias></Alias>
            <Name>Valdosta Lowndes Conf. Ctr.</Name>
            <AddrLine1>1 Meeting Pl</AddrLine1>
            <City>Valdosta</City>
            <StateProvince>GA</StateProvince>
            <PostalCode>316017710</PostalCode>
            <CountryCode>1 Meeting Pl</CountryCode>
            <Contacts>
              <Contact>
                <Name></Name>
                <ContactMethods>
                  <ContactMethod type="" sequenceNum=""></ContactMethod>
                </ContactMethods>
              </Contact>
            </Contacts>
          </Address>
        </BillTo>
      </Payment>
    </Shipment>
```

As you can see, the code is creating a separate shipment block for the second item in the same shipment ID. I need there to be one Shipment ID of "64301.0000000043" and all unique items listed within the "Items" Node. I tried to do a subquery where the Item list in several different ways, but the results were always incorrect.

Comment: Change order of join - Order first, then Order Item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a nested `1:n` relation with a *sub-select*. Your attempt using a join would multiply the parent rows in a normal result set. Therefore you'll see your content within XML multiplied too.

Without sample data it is impossible to provide a secure solution, but you might try to

- take away the `JOIN` and
- use a nested `FOR XML` sub-select

Check this:

```
SELECT [...ManyColumns...]

      ,(
          SELECT        
            ord.freight_class AS '@FreightClass',
            '1' AS '@sequence',
            'lb' AS 'Weight/@units',
            CAST(SUM(ord.extended_weight) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'Weight/*',
            CAST(SUM(ord.container_height) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'Dimensions/@height',
            'in' AS 'Dimensions/@units',
            CAST(SUM(ord.container_width) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'Dimensions/@width',
            CAST(SUM(ord.container_length) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'Dimensions/@length',
            '' AS 'Quantity/@units',
            CAST(SUM(ord.qty) AS NUMERIC(4,1)) AS 'Quantity/*',
            '' AS 'NMFC/*',
            'false' AS 'HazardousMaterial/*'
          FROM t_order_detail ord
          WHERE ord.wh_id=orm.wh_id
            AND ord.order_number=orm.order_number
            AND ord.wh_id = @in_vchWhID
            AND ord.order_number = @in_vchOrderNumber      
          FOR XML PATH('Item'),ROOT('Items'),TYPE
      ) AS 'HandlingUnits/HandlingUnit/*'

      ,[...MoreColumns...]

FROM t_order orm
[...]
```

You'll get into troubles assumeably due to the later `GROUP BY`... Don't know, what you are really trying to achieve.

One solution might be, to place your query with the `GROUP BY`, but without the nested items in a CTE as a normal *derived table*. With this result set you can create your `FOR XML` and add the nested items...